# how to fix the position of mask in snapsvg.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, snap.svg

Here is js code:

```
var cv = Snap('#cv').attr({height: '100%', width: '100%'});

var mskHide = cv.rect().attr({height: '100%', width: '100%', left:0, top:0, fill: '#666'});
var mskShow = cv.circle(200, 200, 150).attr({fill: '#fff'});
var mskG = cv.group(mskHide, mskShow);

var bg = cv.circle(200, 200, 150).attr({fill: '#aaa'});
var customImg = cv.image('http://placehold.it/500/990000').attr({mask: mskG});

//when I drag the customImg， I want mskG fixed position
customImg.drag();
```

You can preview here: http://codepen.io/rlog/pen/eKBlc

**The question is**:  When I drag the `customImg`, how can I fix the position of `mskG`.

The `mskG` is no need move whit `costomImg`

this example is what I want: http://codepen.io/rlog/pen/bAImu

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could basically do what you have in the 2nd codepen.

```
var cv = Snap('#cv').attr({height: '100%', width: '100%'});

var mskHide = cv.rect().attr({height: '100%', width: '100%', left:0, top:0, fill: '#666'});
var mskShow = cv.circle(200, 200, 150).attr({fill: '#fff'});
var mskG = cv.group(mskHide, mskShow);


var bg = cv.circle(200, 200, 150).attr({fill: '#aaa'});

var customImg = cv.image('http://placehold.it/500/990000').attr({mask: mskG });


customImg.drag( myDrag );
function myDrag(dx,dy,x,y) {
  customImg.attr({ x: dx, y: dy })
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cqilt)

If you want a different drag from the example shown to include stored start drag location, you would amend it something like the following...

```
customImg.attr({ x: 0, y: 0})

var move = function(dx,dy) {
this.attr({
      x: +this.data('ox') + +dx,
      y: +this.data('oy') + +dy
    })
} 

var start = function(x,y) {
  this.data('ox', this.attr('x'));
  this.data('oy', this.attr('y'));
}

var end = function(x,y) {}  

customImg.drag( move, start, end )
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ngkLE)

Comment: Thanks!  but myDrag have a little bug when drag.  `customImg.attr({ x: dx, y: dy })` .  `dx` and `dy` maybe not the right value for `x` and `y`. how could I fix it?