# snap.svg / how to drag mask with fixed background image

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

I'm trying to drag a mask over a fixed background-image but I am not getting `.drag(http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.drag)` to work with the mask.

Here is the js code:

```
var s = Snap("#svg");

var Background = s.image("http://placehold.it/350x150", 0, 0, 350, 150);

var Mask = s.path("M10,20h80v40h-40z").attr({
    fill: "#ffffff"
});

Background.attr({ mask: Mask});

Mask.drag();
```

Preview here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqzzLO

How can I drag the mask?

Background position should stay fixed so you move the mask "over" it.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256991/how-to-fix-the-position-of-mask-in-snapsvg-js ?

Comment: Im trying to move the mask, not the image. Already saw that thread and this didn´t help here.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it makes sense to drag a mask, as I don't think it would be a visible entity in itself and it gets sent to defs. Take this example... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGzyMO one mask, used by two elements, what would 'actually' be wanted to be dragged ?

Comment: I´ve made a quick example what i want:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/impffd.jpg

Comment: Yes, but in that example, what you are actually doing is dragging the image. Note, thats different to 'moving' the image. You can still put a drag on the image, but move the mask instead for example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGzyMO (just basics done, you would need to implement storing the offset of the drag etc).

Comment: Thank you!! Already tried something like that with transform but only dragged the mask instead of the image.